# Auto populate in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to auto-populate a list in excel 2013.
For example, the A column would contain ingredients, the B column would contain a name.  The name is associated with the ingredient.  Further to the right on the spreadsheet the column would be titled by the name from B column and the ingredients list would auto-populate beneath that name.

Can someone help me create this?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  Please edit your question to include a mockup or screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have your spreadsheet set up like this:

[image: auto_pop]

You've typed 'Cake' into E1. Then the formula you want in cell E2 is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$8=$E$1,ROW($B$1:$B$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$8=$E$1,ROW($B$1:$B$8)),ROW(1:1)),1))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Then it can simply be dragged down (through the yellow section).

Source: http://thinketg.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/